# VB.Net Unspecified Error /

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, build, compiler-errors

I am currently building a VB.net application and have come across an error.

Upon attempting to build my application i got a long error. i am unable to see this error again but it said something along the lines of "Security Error build will continue without security."

now, whenever i build the application i get "Unspecified Error" when trying to do anything to my database connection (access).

Not sure what to do as i cannot replicate the initial "Security Error" to see what to try and fix.

The Unspecified error is - Systems.data.oledb.oledbexception.
I get this on any code that tries to access the database always errors on opening the connection. example below:

```
Sub Get_History()
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection

    Dim dbProvider As String
    Dim dbSource As String

    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim Query As String

    Try

        dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

        dbSource = "Data Source = " & DOMDatabase

        con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

        con.Open()

        Query = "SELECT SEQUENCE, NOTIFIER_NAME, UPLOAD_DATE from SME_COO WHERE ADVISOR_NAME = '" & Environment.UserName & "'"

        da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(Query, con)

        da.Fill(ds, "CooHistory")

        con.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("An Error Has Occoured: " & ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "ERROR")
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    frmCOOTool.dgvCooHistory.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)

End Sub
```

Rob

Comment: Your question is too unclear to have any valid guess. Perhaps if you add the code that handles your connection and the full error message in the exception (including the inner exception message)

Comment: good point, i have updated the question.

Comment: I have tried running the above code in an new application and received no errors.

it would appear that there is a problem with the project / Visual Studios

Comment: Are you working on your local machine along with the database on the same machine rather than say on a virtual or network location? And to clarify, the exception is thrown on connection open? Do you have rights to modify in the folder the database is located?

Comment: Hi, i am working on my local machine with the database (.mdb) on a network share which i have access to. I have a published version on the same machine that the project is on and this is working fine. i am only getting an error in visual studios.

Comment: I have replicated the Error - 

The security debugging option is set but it requires the Visual Studio hosting process which is unavailable in this debugging configuration. The security debugging option will be disabled. This option may be re-enabled in the Security property page. The debugging session will continue without security debugging

Comment: Here is a [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/913451) that discusses this as a bug. Did you do anything in the security tab with ClickOnce and Zone settings?

Comment: I didn't touch anything in the security tab. The only options i have are "Enable ClickOnce Security settings" with either "this is a full trust application" or "this is a partial tryst application" still get the error with all combinations.

i am rather confused. Everything in the project properties looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Managed to fix this, Apparently it is a Bug with Visual Studios.

I have found a work around by simply copy and pasting everything into a new solution and disabling "Enable the Visual Studio Hosting Process"

Tedious but it works.